# PHP link two buttons together

Tags: php, button, iframe

I have a iFrame inside an php page.
The iFrame contains form (in asp), can I link a button outside the iFrame to the button outside?
Thanks!

Comment: Define "link"... Link how?

Comment: **"link a button outside the iFrame to the button outside"** ? means link inside of frame to outside?

Comment: You should take out the ASP and PHP portions to simplify the problem since they're totally irrelevant.

Comment: Almost certainly not. Accessing the iframe from the main page will be blocked because they are not from the same origin. (Unless you have control of the ASP server and send a header allowing access).

Comment: @Chris: Except if they are.  Of course that wouldn't allow much flexibility though unless the URL changes.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I'm assuming they are not because the asker mentioned one is written in PHP and the other in ASP. Barring some weird reverse proxy setup that means they will at least be on different ports and probably on different servers too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a button on main page to click a button on iframe page using jquery.

for example in main page if you have:

**Main page HTML Sample**:

```
<button id="parentbutton">click me</button>

<iframe name='select_frame' src='http://www.barzegari.com/DEAFULT.ASP'></iframe>
```

**JQUERY in main page:**

```
$("#parentbutton").click(function(){
  $('input:button[name=save]').click(function() {  
     $('iframe[name=select_frame]').contents().find('#mybuttonid').click();
   });
});
```

**in iframe html:**

you have a button with id(clientid) like "mybuttonid";

Answer (score 0):

this is prevent by cross domain privacy, but you can do it by this way,
in your php page, use file_get_contents to get asp content, filter get form script and paste to php page, by this way, you can do everything as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing iframe content from other URL will give you the error **Refused to display 'YOUR_URL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'**. This is because, all the server restricts the access of iframe content from third party website for security purpose. If you are not getting the above error, try the below code in your PHP file.

```js
$("#phpbutton").click(function(){
  var iframe = $('#aspiframe').contents();
  iframe.find("#aspbutton").click();
});
```

```html
<iframe id='aspiframe' src='YOUR_ASP_URL'></iframe>
<input type="button" id="phpbutton">click here</button>
```

**Note :** Make sure you have replaced with correct IDs.